# Remove double quotes around space and null on a output tsv file from copyMerge on Scala Spark

Tags: scala, csv, hdfs, apache-spark-sql

When I am merging part files via `FileUtil.copyMerge` function from a Dataframe created from an HQL I am getting `""` around spaces and nulls on my final text file on HDFS. Here is what I am doing.

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs._
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration

val dir = "your/output/folder"

val selectedData= hiveContext.sql(executeHQL)

// Pick the header  
val selectedDataHeader = selectedData.limit(0)

// write header to a file for merging   
selectedDataHeader.write
  .format("csv")
  .option("header", "true").option("delimiter", "\t")
  .save(dir + "/header")

// create the part files  
selectedData.write
  .format("csv")
  .option("header", "false").option("delimiter", "\t")
  .save(dir + "/parts")     

val configuration = new Configuration()
val fs = FileSystem.get(configuration)

// merge header and all part files to one 
FileUtil.copyMerge(
  fs, new Path(dir +  "/header"),
  fs, new Path(dir  +"/parts/header"),
  false, configuration, "")

// Write extracts to file
FileUtil.copyMerge(
  fs, new Path(dir + "/parts/"),
  fs, new Path(dir + "/destination.txt"),
  false, configuration, null)
```

So problem is on /destination.txt it looks like below

```
""    ABC  XYZ PQR  ""  XYZ2  
ROW2  ABC2 XYZ PQR2 ""  XYZ3
```

How do I remove the `""` around spaces or null values? Note the part files do not show the "" though.

Comment: I tried your code and it doesn't produce empty quotes in destination.txt. Which version of Spark are you using? I should mention that I'm using this input: `List(("", "ABC", "XYZ", "PQR", null, "XYZ2"), ("ROW2", "ABC2", "XYZ", "PQR2", "", "XYZ3")).toDF`.

Comment: I am using spark 1.6 on cloudera hadoop distribution. destination.txt is on HDFS

Comment: With 2.2 I don't seem to have the issue; but I'm not sure that's the issue. I can't understand how the issue could only be of destination.txt and not in part* files, which would make it a problem related to hadoop.fs, but I don't see how a simple merge of lines would bring up this problem.